# Function returns seemingly random number instead of the value of returned variable

Tags: c++, algorithm, function

So, I'm writing this simple code (when finished, it should count the values of n polynomials, each of r degree, in n points. I also cannot use loops, I ought to do the stuff in recursive functions - but it's not done yet and the topic has nothing to do with my problem).

So, the code so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void wypisz(int i, int k, int* c)
{
  if (i<k) cout<<*(c+i)<<" ";
  else return;
  i++;
  wypisz(i,k,c);
}

void podaj(int i, int k, int* c)
{
  if (i<k) cin>>*(c+i);
  else return;
  i++; 
  podaj(i,k,c);
}

int wynik (int i, int k, int* c, int su, int mn)
{
  int y;
  if (i<k) {
    cin>>y;
    su+=y*mn;
    mn*=*c;
  }
  else {cout<<su<<endl; return su;}
  i++;
  wynik (i, k, c, su, mn);
}

int main(){

  int m,n,r;
  cin>>m;
  int tab[m];

  podaj(0,m,tab);
  wypisz(0,m,tab);

  cin>>r;
  cout<<wynik(0,r,tab,0,1);
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

It counts the first polynomial in first point well, but only in function. When calling

```
cout<<su;
```

just before terminating the wynik() function, it gives correct value, but when calling

```
cout<<wynik(0,r,tab,0,1);
```

in main(), it gives much higher, seemingly random value.

Could anyone tell me why?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think your wynik function is missing a "return" in its last line

Comment: More descriptive variable names would go a long way toward making this more readable.  And you're talking about *recursive* functions in your problem description?

Comment: Seems to be a common misunderstanding for some reason. Return is still needed even when doing recursion.

Comment: Crank up the warning level on your compiler. `g++ -Wall -Wextra` warns that `system` is undeclared (you need `#include <cstdlib>`, that `n` is unused, and that control reaches the end of `wynik` without returning a result.

Comment: @KeithThompson `system` can be used in Windows with just including `<iostream>`.

Comment: @PawełStawarz: That's non-standard. As I understand it, C++ standard headers *may or may not* `#include` other standard headers. There's no guarantee that `#include <iostream>` will make the declaration of `system` visible. To be sure, just add the `#include <cstdlib>`; it can't hurt.

Comment: @KeithThompson all the IDE's (Visual Studio, DevC++, NetBeans) **do** include it in `<iostream>`. Besides - if that was the case, the code wouldn't compile. And it did from the start.

Comment: @PawełStawarz: And how is that inconsistent with what I wrote in my previous comment? Calling `system()` without `#include <cstdlib>` or `#include <stdlib.h>` is non-portable. It might happen to work on some implementations. It fails on others.

Comment: @KeithThompson it's not related with the question. And couldn't be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41675/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-pawel-stawarz)

Answer (score 4):

In your `wynik` function, when doing recursion, you aren't exacly returning the calculated value... you should change the last line from:

```
wynik (i, k, c, su, mn);
```

to

```
return wynik(i, k, c, su, mn);
```

Or, even better, change the whole function so it looks clear:

```
int wynik (int i, int k, int* c, int su, int mn)
{
  int y;
  if (i<k) {
    cin>>y;
    su+=y*mn;
    mn*=*c;
    return wynik (++i, k, c, su, mn);
  }
  else return su;
}
```

Comment: That totally helped, thanks! 

Do you mind explaining to me (just for the better understanding of what I'm doing), why this caused the correct value of su to be lost just at the terminating of the function, instead of sooner?

Comment: @user The code following your `else`-clause never returned a value using a `return`-statement. In the compiled code an integer value is usually returned in the `eax` register (or `rax` for 64-bit). The missing `return`-statement never writes the correct value to this register. When the function returns, whatever value is in the register is interpreted as the return value. Thus leading to seemingly random values returned.

Comment: Lets say you called `wynik`, and it called itself inside. In the 2nd call, the function calculated **X**, sent it to `cout`, and finished. Then the control went back to the first `wynik` function and the value got lost there, because you didn't return it from there.

Comment: Ok, I've finished the code, got 100%. Thank you. Sorry that it was not clear, I avoid correcting myself in this matter on purpose, cause making completely clear and optimal code is like asking to be accused of plagiarism... Which is kinda sad when you'd think about what the university teaches us.